# What does "render" mean in Django?

Tags: python, django

What does it mean to "render a template" or to "render a form" in Django?
Example 1: "Generally a view retrieves data according to the parameters, loads a template and renders the template with the retrieved data.

Example 2: "Rendering a form in a template involves nearly the same work as rendering any other kind of object"

Would the meaning of render in the above two examples be to "provide" or give"?

Answer (score 2):

[These etymologies given on Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/render#Etymology_1) stand:

> (transitive) To interpret, give an interpretation or rendition of.
>
> (transitive) To translate into another language.
>
> (transitive, computer graphics) To transform (a model) into a display on the screen or other media.

That is, the code describing your form, or the template describing your page, is *rendered* into the final HTML form.

Comment: In plain English would that be "inserted"?

Comment: I found another explanation in the link you provided. (transitive, computer graphics) To transform (a model) into a display on the screen or other media. 
rendering images

Comment: Yes... that's literally the third line in my post.

Comment: Yes it is. So it would basically mean if the form is rendered , that the form is displayed?

Comment: Not _exactly_ , it's not displayed until it ends up on an user's screen. But it's rendered into a form palatable by the user's browser.

Comment: Right. Now I got it. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

Rendering a template is indeed always about producing content, but for a slightly wider description of content. It could be a chunk of html, for example an ajax call to get new items might produce some html describing the new items, but it doesn't have to be.

creds. Frederick Cheung

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for generic term "templating": https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating

TLDR;
It's common practice to split View and Models. In this case View is templates, e.g. html file.